# CD4069 toggle switch

Tags: cmos, buffer, schmitt-trigger, trigger, toggle-switch

How to connect the trigger out instead of the switch? Like a toggle switch. The first trigger out activates the relay and remains ON infinity, the second trigger out deactivates the relay and remains OFF infinity.[image]

Comment: Where did this circuit come from? What do you mean by 'trigger out'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I found circuit from here: http://circuits-projects.blogspot.com/2012/08/alternating-on-off-switch-with-ic-4069.html When the NE555 OUT is high then the trigger is activated.

Comment: the easy way is to use a 1/2 of dual "D" FF with feedback from Qbar to D input and R pull down and C to switch to V+

Comment: It's also called a divide by two circuit